# Installing ungit on Windows XP error: C:/Documents: No such file or directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, windows-xp, npm

[Ungit](https://github.com/FredrikNoren/ungit) looks the perfect tool to learn how git works, as it gives a graphical interface to understand what is going on. I want to share this [video explanation](http://youtu.be/hkBVAi3oKvo) (very useful to understand how git works even if you are not planning to use ungit).

It has synchronized my local repository perfectly. Unfortunately, when I have typed the bickbucket git url, it has produced the following error:

*Ungit tried to run a git command that resulted in an unhandled error. An automatic bug report was sent.*

*Command (I didn't type it myself, ungit sent it automatically after typing the URL*

```
git -c color.ui=false -c core.quotepath=false -c core.pager=cat -c credential.helper="C:/Documents and Settings/ch/Datos de programa/npm/node_modules/ungit/bin/credentials-helper 0"  ls-remote --tags prototype-towunderlist2
```

*Error*. The error is **probably because there are spaces in *C:/Documents and Settings*:**

```
Error: Command failed: C:/Documents and Settings/ch/Datos de programa/npm/node_modules/ungit/bin/credentials-helper 0 get: C:/Documents: No such file or directory
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://chelder86@bitbucket.org': No such file or directory
```

It looks a Windows issue for me, so I have published it in stackoverflow instead the [ungit bug report system](https://github.com/FredrikNoren/ungit/issues/309).

---

**UPDATE 1**. I have found out how to get by, but I got another error:

```
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://chelder86@bitbucket.org/chelder86/prototype-towunderlist2.git/'
```

To get by, I did the following. I opened a new cmd (command line). I went into the repository directory. I typed the same command but **adding single quotes into the double quotes** as follows:

Instead:

```
"C:/Documents and Settings/ch/Datos de programa/npm/node_modules/ungit/bin/credentials-helper 0"
```

I typed:

```
"C:/'Documents and Settings'/ch/'Datos de programa'/npm/node_modules/ungit/bin/credentials-helper 0"
```

Then, a form appeared in the browser to wrote my username and password. I wrote them, and the new error appeared in the command line (not in the user interface of the browser).

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot of the new error]

---

**UPDATE 2**: the line where is generated the path `"C:/Documents and Settings/ch/Datos de programa/npm/node_modules/ungit/bin/credentials-helper 0"` is located in `C:\Documents and Settings\ch\Datos de programa\npm\node_modules\ungit\source\git-api.js`. It is:

```
  function credentialsOption(socketId) {
    var credentialsHelperPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'bin', 'credentials-helper').replace(/\\/g, '/');
    return '-c credential.helper="' + credentialsHelperPath + ' ' + socketId + '" ';
  }
```

I'm not a Javascript expert, so I need some time to find out how to build the correct path...

---

**UPDATE 3**: the temporal fix of the code of UPDATE 2 is the following:

[It is a fix, so I wrote it as an answer instead]

Comment: try using `credential.helper="'C:/Documents and Settings/ch/Datos de programa/npm/node_modules/ungit/bin/credentials-helper' 0"` in the ls-remote command

Comment: @NevikRehnel, ungit sent that command (I didn't typed it myself). Do you know where ungit has that line to modify it?

Comment: Yeah, I think you're more likely to get an answer here [FredrikNoren/ungit/issues/309](https://github.com/FredrikNoren/ungit/issues/309)

Comment: I realize I should add 2 tags:  node.js and npm (because ungit requires them, so probably who knows about those topics, will know about this error)

Comment: Havingspaces in directory - Windows has responded as expected - ungot need to call the script in a way so that spaces are dealt with e.g. put the path inside quotes - so an ungit issue not Windows

Comment: I partially solved it following your idea @NevikRehnel. See UPDATE 1

Comment: OK @Mark. I have typed single quotes inside double quotes to partially fix it. I never did something similar in Windows. See UPDATE 1.

Comment: The whole path needs to be in one set of quotes not parts and exactly as Nevik suggests which is not one you show here - and in windows command line try with the c:\Documents and Settings path not the one you are in which is d:\ch\Documents then you would have to do this often

Comment: @Mark, if I write what Nevik suggested, I get the following error: `git: 'credential-C:/Documents and Settings/ch/Datos de programa/npm/node_modules/ungit/bin/credentials-helper' is not a git command. See 'git --help' fatal: could not read Password for 'https://chelder86@bitbucket.org': No such file or directory´`. On the other hand, I have my repository in D. Document and Settings is in C.

Comment: I had a similar problem with git extensions. I just ran manual ran the git-credential-winstore.exe. Do you have that file or the file credentials-helper under the specified folder (.../npm/node_modules/ungit/bin/)? If yes try to manually run it and try the command again. That helped me on a similar issue.

Comment: Why not use [SourceTree](http://sourcetreeapp.com/)?

Comment: @MitjaBezenšek, unfortunately, `C:\Documents and Settings\ch\Datos de programa\npm\node_modules\ungit\bin` has only two files: `credentials-helper` and `ungit`. On the other hand, there isn't a directory named `ungit` in `C:\Archivos de programa\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules`

Comment: @JaKXz, [SourceTree is not compatible with Windows XP](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/150135/install-on-windows-xp). Anyway, the "solution" could be looking for a different software :(

Comment: Is credentials-helper executable file? Try that one if it is.

Comment: No, @MitjaBezenšek. It has readable code inside. It looks the code which gets the username and password from the internet browser form (I read: `http.get('http://localhost:' + config.port + '/api/credentials?socketId=' + process.argv[2],` **...** `console.log('username=' + data.username); console.log('password=' + (data.password ? data.password : ''));` **...**)

Comment: I found out the line where the path is generated. See **UPDATE 2**.

Comment: I did a fix to get by, but I get a different error. See **UPDATE 3**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **temporal fix** of the code of **UPDATE 2** is the following:

```
  function credentialsOption(socketId) {
    var credentialsHelperPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'bin', 'credentials-helper').replace(/\\/g, '/'); 
    var botchedFix1 = '-c credential.helper="' + credentialsHelperPath + ' ' + socketId + '" ';
    var botchedFix2 = botchedFix1.replace("Documents and Settings","'Documents and Settings'");  
    botchedFix2 = botchedFix2.replace("Datos de programa","'Datos de programa'");   
    return botchedFix2; 
    }
```

Then, if I click on Fetch Nodes from prototype-towunderlist2 in the user interface of the internet browser (Firefox), I can enter my username and password. **Unfortutately, I got a new error**:

Command

```
git -c color.ui=false -c core.quotepath=false -c core.pager=cat -c credential.helper="C:/'Documents and Settings'/ch/'Datos de programa'/npm/node_modules/ungit/bin/credentials-helper 0"  ls-remote --tags prototype-towunderlist2
```

Error

```
Error: Command failed: fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://chelder86@bitbucket.org/chelder86/prototype-towunderlist2.git/'
```

**However**, if you copy and paste the **same command in a new cmd** (command line), it seems **working perfectly**. **Push is also working**.

Feel free to improve my ugly solution!